# File structure of Social Engine Modules

Tags: socialengine

can anybody tell me the file structure of Social Engine 4 Modules i.e. what files or folder are required which are optional etc.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Required directories/files seem to be controller/view/model/settings.  The rest seem to be optional, at least on the modules I've built,though I just have an empty directory with an .htaccess file in each.